# Split tab separated string into array in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, debian

```
line="\t\t\t1\t2\t\t3"
```

What I do:

```
IFS=$'\t'  DIRS=($line);
```

What I want to get:

```
DIRS[0]=NULL; DIRS[1]=NULL; DIRS[2]=NULL; DIRS[3]=1;DIRS[4]=2;DIRS[5]=NULL;DIRS[6]=3;
```

What I actually get:

```
DIRS[0]=1; DIRS[1]=2; DIRS[2]=3
```

Is that possible to get what I want to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash treats whitespace specially in IFS:

> If  IFS  has a value other than the default, then
>          sequences of the whitespace characters space and tab are ignored at the beginning and  end  of  the
>          word,  as  long  as  the whitespace character is in the value of IFS (an IFS whitespace character).
>          Any character in IFS that is not IFS whitespace, along with any adjacent IFS whitespace characters,
>          delimits  a field.  A sequence of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.

So, use a non-whitespace character. (BTW, I use `$'\t'` for a tab, search `man bash` for *Quoting*)

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$'\t\t\t1\t2\t\t3'

IFS=$':' DIRS=(${line//$'\t'/:})       # Replace tabs with colons.

for (( i=0 ; i<${#DIRS[@]} ; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: [${DIRS[i]}]"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for them. But instead of using ':' as delimiter I use '|'.

Comment: @TrueBlue10: Use whatever can't occur in the `$line`.